# $\left\lvert a - b \right\rvert \le \left\lvert a - c \right\rvert + \left\lvert c-d \right\rvert + \left\lvert d - b \right\rvert$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification

Let us show that: $$\left\lvert a - b \right\rvert  \le \left\lvert a - c \right\rvert + \left\lvert c-d \right\rvert + \left\lvert d - b \right\rvert$$

Then,
$$a - b = (a - c) + (c - d + d - b) \le \left\lvert a - c \right\rvert + \left\lvert c - d + d - b \right\rvert \le \left\lvert a - c \right\rvert + \left\lvert c - d \right\rvert + \left\lvert d - b \right\rvert $$

$QED$

Thanks

Comment: It is correct if you insert two absolute value signs.

Comment: I don't see what you mean, could you show me where shall I insert that ?

Comment: What did you prove? Did you prove exactly the inequlaity you are asked to prove?

Comment: You've currently only shown that $a - b \leq |a-c| + |c-d| + |d-b|$. To prove that $|a-b|  \leq |a-c| + |c-d| + |d-b| $ you'll also need to show that $ a - b \geq - ( |a-c| + |c-d| + |d-b|)$.

Comment: If you put your proof in modulus from scratch, then it give true result: start with $|a-b|$.

Comment: My bad, Thanks guys.

Comment: "then" is not the word you want.  "then" assumes you have already accepted the statement and what follows is a result.  You *haven't* accepted the statement and what follows explains why it is true.

Comment: Also, just to be nitpicky, you haven't actually *asked* a question.  How do you want us to respond too this post?  Why are you posting it?

Comment: Alright, that's clear, so what should be the correct keyword here? I wanted to know if my line of reasoning was true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not complete. Your idea is to apply the triangle inequality and is good, but your argument starts with $a-b$, not $|a-b|$. Here's an easy fix:
\begin{align}
|a-b|&=|a-c+c-b|\\[4px]
&\le|a-c|+|c-b|\\[4px]
&=|a-c|+|c-d+d-b|\\[4px]
&\le|a-c|+|c-d|+|d-b|
\end{align}
More generally, given $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$, we have
$$
|x_0-x_n|\le|x_0-x_1|+|x_1-x_2|+\dots+|x_{n-1}-x_n|
$$
which can be proved by induction on $n$.

The base case, for $n=1$ is obvious. Suppose the inequality holds for $n$; then
$$
|x_0-x_{n+1}|=|x_0-x_n+x_n-x_{n+1}|\le|x_0-x_n|+|x_n-x_{n+1}|
$$
Now apply the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to prove the general case but could you give some hints about proving $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ ?

Comment: @roger_godement I added the hint.

Comment: Then we get: $|x_0-x_{n+1}|\le|x_0-x_1|+|x_1-x_2|+\dots+|x_{n-1}-x_n|+|x_n-x_{n+1}|$ and we are done ?

Comment: @roger_godement Yes, indeed.